# Is it OK to remove unwanted dot files from react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I want to clean my react-native directory...So I removed:

- `_editorconfig`
- `.buckconfig`
- `.eslintrc.js`
- `.flowconfig`
- `.gitattributes`
- `.prettierrc.js`
- `.watchmanconfig`

So is it OK to remove those files?

Comment: I dunno, but probably best to check that _before_ removing!

Comment: Depends on whether you plan to use the tools which read their config from those files ...

Comment: most of them safe to remove... But I am not sure about `.buckconfig` and `.flowconfig`